# Перебор в цикле

Tags: php, циклы

Добрый день, подскажите почему перебирает только один ключ.

```
while($station_row = $adb->fetch_array($sql)) {
            $station = $station_row['kod'];
            $info = '';
                while($stations_row = $adb->fetch_array($sql)) {
                $stations = $stations_row['kod'];
                    $info .= "$station : $stations <br />";
                }       
                echo $info;
            }
Выводит 
        888004 : 35508 
        888004 : 254905 
        888004 : 510806
А нужно
        888004 : 35508 
        888004 : 254905 
        888004 : 510806
        35508 : 888004
        35508 : 254905 
        35508 : 510806 
и так далее... в чем проблема?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что **`$station_row = $adb->fetch_array($sql)`** выбирает из $adb следующую запись. В итоге получается так, что внешним циклом ты берешь 1-ую запись, а внутренним циклом все оставшиеся. Когда дело до ходит до внешнего цикла то для него в $adb уже все записи закончились.

**Решение:**

Попробуйте для начала перевести все из $adb в массив, и перебирать уже массив )

**Например:**

```
$arr = array();
while($station_row = $adb->fetch_array($sql)) {
    $arr[] = $station_row;
}

foreach ($arr as $row)
{
    foreach ($arr as $row2)
    {
        echo $row['kod'],':',$row2['kod'],'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: теперь понятно, спс.

Comment: while($station_row = $adb->fetch_array($sql)) {
    $station = $station_row['kod'];
    if (!isset($data[$station_row['kod']])) 
     $data[$station_row['kod']]= array();
     
    }
    foreach($data as $key => $serdata) {
     $data_total = count($data);
     for ($i = 0; $i < $data_total; ++$i) {
      echo $key. '<br />';
     }
    }

Comment: не подскажешь как правильно перебрать?

Comment: @machanics в ответе добавил пример :) не проверял, но должно работать :) , во втором фориче можно добавить проверку, чтобы коды не совпадали )

Comment: спс! все ок!

Comment: пожалуйста )

Comment: можно ещё указатель на текущую запись сбрасывать.